# How to differentiate whether the image captured by vision api face detector is real time or from video frame

Tags: android, api, kotlin, vision

I'm using google vision api for face detection, and once the face is detected I'm capturing the image. But if suppose a video is shown instead of real face, that is also getting detected. How to consider only the real time face alone for face detection?

I tried detecting eye blinks, but again if the video of a person is having eyeblink then that also getting failed.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiating between a realtime face detection system and a video frame can be difficult. However, there are a few approaches that you could use to help you identify whether the face detection is happening in real-time or if it's a video frame.

One approach would be to check if the faces detected are **consistent over time**. A real-time face detection system will detect the same face repeatedly, even if there are slight changes in the lighting or pose. On the other hand, a video frame will show different faces, usually without any movement or changes. So, if the detected faces are changing frequently, it's more likely to be a video frame.

Another approach would be to **check for movement**. A real-time face detection system will detect faces in motion, where as a video frame will show static faces. So, if the detected face is not moving at all, it's more likely to be a video frame.

You could also **analyze the metadata of the image** to see if there's any information about the capture time or the device used to capture the image. Real-time face detection systems usually capture images in real-time, while video frames will have metadata that indicates the device and time of capture.

Additionally, you can **analyze the image content itself** to look for sings that it may be a video frame. For instance, you could check for repeating patterns in the background or detect artifacts introduced by video compresion.

It's worth noting that none of these approaches is perfect, and you may need to combine several approches to improve the accuracy.